# Back Button Not working properly

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In parent form I am displaying multiple child forms ,I am opening `child2 from child1`,`child3 from child2` till this it is working fine and form are getting open in parent form,  but when I want to go back from `child2 to child1` than `child1 form` is getting open outside parent form ,what can be right code for back button ?

**code for opening `chil2 form` written in `child1 form`**

```
private void btnEngClgList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ShowEngClgList engfrm = new ShowEngClgList(LoginName);
    engfrm.MdiParent = this.ParentForm;
    this.Hide();
    engfrm.Show();
}
```

**back button code written in `child2 Form`**

```
private void toolStripBtnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    this.Close();
    MainForm mnfrm = new MainForm(lname);
    mnfrm.MdiParent = this.ParentForm;
    mnfrm.Show();
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here...what is supposed to happen when you open/close the child forms?

Comment: I am trying to navigate to and from child forms,by simply creating back button

Comment: Clearly you don't want to create a new main form, you already have one.  It is this.MdiParent.  You definitely need to re-think how Back is going to work, you are not close.  It makes little sense in an MDI application.

Comment: @Hans Passant That's what I am searching for ,Can you suggest any solution?

Answer (score 0):

U can do like this:

```
((this.Parent) as Window).show();
```

Comment: can u explain in which form should i write this and where,and what this line of code will do exactly

Comment: U should write it in main form.After closing the this window. It will
the parent window in this case window1.

Comment: I have written it after `Initializecomponenet()` of `parent form`  ,but its not working and giving me error for convert type

Comment: Write it here:
private void toolStripBtnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36918/discussion-between-durga-and-ch-smrutiranjan-parida)